# Event firing when ComboBox.Items count changed?

Tags: wpf, events, combobox, count, items

I couldn't find a proper event which fires when my ComboBox.Items count changed. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind ComboBox ItemsSource to ObservableCollection, then you can catch the event CollectionChanged of ObservableCollection

EDIT:

In wpf it is recommended to use binding instead of accessing UI element properties directly, of course better to use MVVM, but you can live without it too

in your Windows or UserControls C# code you can keep property like this

```
public ObservableCollection<string> MyCollection{get;set;}
```

Initialize it in constructor

```
MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>()
MyCollection.CollectionChanged += SomeMethod;
```

than name your UserControl in xaml like this

```
<UserControl Name="myUserControl".../>
```

write your ComboBox like this

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=myUserControl, Path=MyCollection}"...
```

now instead of adding and removing items to combobox element, add tham to MyCollection, they will appear in combobox

Hope this helps

Comment: I marked it as answer even though I couldn't figure out to do it yet. Google gave me alot of threads about this issue but I don't really know how to do so... Nevertheless: Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I add more detailed description how to do that @theknut, please take a look

Answer (score 0):

Don't think that there is any event to fire when ComboBox.Items count changed. You probably should do the code when you add or remove the items.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub
```

OR

```
protected void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```