# Does ComboBox.Items.Add() trigger an event?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

If I make a ComboBoxItem like this:
`ComboBoxItem cbi = new ComboBoxItem();`

Add a few properties to `cbi`, like Content and Tag.

And add that ComboBoxItem to a ComboBox like this:
`cbxSelectClan.Items.Add(cbi);`

Will `cbxSelecteClan` trigger any event ? (like `SelectionChanged`, `TargetUpdated` or any other possible event)

Comment: Create a small application and try it out and see if it triggers it. There are many times as a programmer you will have such questions, the best thing is just to try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not by itself. You will need to bind the control to a collection that does provide such events, such as `ObservableCollection`. Maybe the following answer will help: [Event firing when ComboBox.Items count changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9126542/2778027)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just wanted te be sure if it triggered an event because if it would, I would need to catch and cancel it.